# Tic tac toe game Type error None python

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to create a tic tac toe game with the `board` values `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]` coming from the front end and going back to the back end and then all this values being returned to the front end with a X from the user or a 0 from the random maths.
The first time I input a value, it works, but the second time I input a value I get this error.

```
if board[cell1]  == char and board[cell2] == char and board[cell3] == char:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The error sounds like that the board list disappears but when I print the board on my codes it shows that the board is there.

```
def tic(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
      body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')

      body = json.loads(body_unicode)

      input_str = body['value']

      input = int(input_str)

      board = body['x']
      print(board) # Here I see the board is always there


      if board[input] != 'x' and board[input] != 'o':
         board[input] = 'x'

         if check_match(board,'x') == True:
            winner = 'x'
            return JsonResponse({'input': input, 'board': board, 'winner': winner})

         board = opponent_fun(board)
         if check_match(board,'o') == True:
            winner = 'o'
            return JsonResponse({'input': input, 'board': board, 'winner': winner})

         else:
            winner = 0
            return JsonResponse({'input': input, 'board': board, 'winner': winner})
      else:
         return JsonResponse({'taken' : 'place already taken'})


def opponent_fun(board):
      random.seed()
      opponent = random.randint(0, 8)

      if board[opponent] != 'o' and board[opponent] != 'x':
         board[opponent] = 'o'
         return board

      else:
         opponent_fun(board)


def check(board, char, cell1, cell2, cell3):
    if board[cell1]  == char and board[cell2] == char and board[cell3] == char:
        return True

def check_match(board,char):
    if check(board,char, 0,1,2):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 3,4,5):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 6,7,8):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 2,4,6):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 0,4,8):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 1,4,7):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 2,5,8):
        return True
    if check(board,char, 6,7,8):
        return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the else block of the opponent_fun function, you are not returning the result of the recursive call.  Changing it to this should fix it.

```
def opponent_fun(board):
  random.seed()
  opponent = random.randint(0, 8)

  if board[opponent] != 'o' and board[opponent] != 'x':
     board[opponent] = 'o'
     return board
  else:
     return opponent_fun(board)
```

This is happening because a function always returns a value to the direct caller, not all the way up to the first caller.  So each time you call a function recursively, you need to return also.